# Enable SerialPort DataReceived event once data has been sent

Tags: c#, events, serial-port

So I am talking to device, and the TX and RX pins are actually tied together internally.
When I send data to the device, I see the same data being picked up by my `SerialPort.DataReceived` event.

I would like to only have this event trigger once the data has been sent.
I have tried simply unsubscribing before I send data, then subscribing once `SerialPort.Write` is called, but the write function looks to be handled in a separate thread, so I still receive the data, as the subscribe happens immediately.

There does not look to be a "DataSendComplete" type of event I could use to subscribe.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I have tried adding

```
if (serialPort.BytesToWrite != 0)
            return;
```

But all of the data has already been sent by the time the event triggers I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this reliably, you cannot possibly get the timing right.  The exact time the driver physically transmits the data from the transmit buffer to the UART as well as the exact time the UART transmits the bytes in the FIFO cannot be determined in a user mode program.  Only the driver would have a shot at it and it doesn't have this option.

You'll need to look for an option to turn the echo off in the device, like the ATE0 command if this device uses the Hayes command set.  Or just discard the number of bytes that you sent in your DataReceived event handler.